# How to include items in credit memo transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo, transactional-mail

It seems that the product level items aren't available in the Magento credit memo transactional email, nor is a balance displayed - it gets you to login via My Account to view it.

Is there a reason behind this? What would be required to achieve this - would the information be available at a transactional email template or, would I need to extend Magento?